# Scheme: why this result when redefining a predefined operator?

Tags: operators, scheme, guile

I received an unexpected result when redefining the `+` operator in a scheme program using `guile`. I should point out that this occurred while experimenting to try to understand the language; there's no attempt here to write a useful program.

Here's the code:

```
(define (f a b) 4)

(define (show)
  (display (+ 2 2)) (display ",") (display (f 2 2)) (newline))

(show)
; guile & mit-scheme: "4,4"

(define (+ a b) 5)
(define (f a b) 5)

(show)
; mit-scheme: "5,5"
; guile: "4,5" - this "4" is the unexpected result

(define (show)
  (display (+ 2 2)) (display ",") (display (f 2 2)) (newline))

(show)
; guile & mit-scheme: "5,5"
```

In `guile` the function `show` uses the predefined definition of `+` even after I've redefined it, though it uses the new definition of `f`. I have to redefine `show` to get it to recognise the new definition of `+`. In `mit-scheme` both new definitions are recognised immediately, which is what I was expecting to happen. Also, any further definitions of `+` are instantly recognised by both interpreters without having to redefine `show`.

What's going on behind the scenes in `guile` to make it bind references to these redefined operators differently?

And why the difference between the two interpreters?

Comment: Interesting.  +1 for very clearly explained question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Guile is wrongly assuming that nobody is crazy enough to redefine `+` and is making the optimization of folding `(+ 2 2) => 4`, making `(display (+ 2 2))` become `(display 4)`.  That would explain why you need to redefine `show` in order to reflect your new `+`.

Indeed, if you first do `(define (+ a b) 4)` at the very top of your program, Guile will not do that optimization and you will get `4,4` and `5,5` just like MIT Scheme.

**Edit:** Actually, it looks like Guile will optimize `+` to reference its own native `+` construct, meaning that even if you don't use constants (no constant folding) you will still be unable to redefine `+` like that.